# Hive table to MySQL table conversion

Tags: mysql, hive

HIVE DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE emp(name varchar(255),job varchar(255)) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat' LOCATION 'hdfs://empdata.db/emp' TBLPROPERTIES ('numFiles'='1','numRows'='0','rawDataSize'='0','totalSize'='487358','transient_lastDdlTime'='1578896334');
```

MySQL DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE emp(name varchar(255),job varchar(255));
```

how to handle row delimiter, format of storing and table properties which mention in the hive query while creating MySQL ddl?

Comment: There is no equivalent in mysql.

Comment: if it is not equivalent how can i handle this scenario?